# Error Websocket Ratchet

Tags: javascript, php, push-notification, websocket

estoy intentando implementar notificaciones en tiempo real en mi sistema web php, esto lo estoy haciendo a través de websockets, intento crear una conexión cliente-websocket pero al momento de correrlo me sale el siguiente error, ya que no encuentra las clases:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código php donde llamo a esas clases es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código donde hago la conexión del websocket:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mi archivo composer.json es el siguiente:

```
{
    "name": "local/public_html",
    "require": {
        "firebase/php-jwt": "^5.4",
        "mikey179/vfsstream": "^1.6",
        "mpdf/mpdf": "^8.0",
        "psr/simple-cache": "^1.0",
        "genkgo/xsl": "^0.6.11",
        "chillerlan/php-qrcode": "^2.0",
        "cboden/ratchet": "^0.4.4",
        "ratchet/pawl": "^0.4.1"
    }
}
```

Por mas que busco no encuentro esas clases, alguien podría decirme a que se debe o que proceso de instalación debo llevar para que se pongan correctamente.

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. EL código va como texto, por favor. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).